# Список точке WiFI пуст

Tags: android, wifi

Мне нужно получить список точек доступа WiFi, для этого у меня есть следующий код

Код класса:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var wifiManager : WifiManager
    private val mWifiScanReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(c: Context, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.action.equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
                formList()
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        wifiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        formList()
        registerReceiver(
            mWifiScanReceiver,
            IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)
        )
        wifiManager.startScan()
    }
    private fun formList(){
        val mScanResults = wifiManager.scanResults
        mScanResults.sortBy { WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(it.level, 5) }
        val data = mScanResults.map { it.SSID + " " + WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(it.level, 5).toString() }
        wifiList.adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data)
    }
}
```

Разрешения в манифесте:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Однако `scanResults` всегда пуст и кроме того `onReceive` вообще не вызывается.

Проверял на телефоне через отладку по USB и так же ставил скомпилированный apk, при этом пробовал включать и выключать WiFi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

на WiFi вроде бы надо еще и подтверждение пользователя. Что-то вроде такого

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE),
                    
                )
                makeEnableLocationServices(activity.applicationContext)
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE),
                    
                )
            }
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @kust если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.